# How to calculate total price in django?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm building an ecommerce website and trying to calculate the total price of the products in views.py but I'm getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
@login_required(login_url='/customer/login')
@customer()
def addtocart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        buyer = request.user.is_customer
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(buyer = buyer)

        amount = 0.00
        cart_products = [p for p in Cart.objects.all() if p.buyer == buyer]

        if cart_products:
            for p in cart_products:
                t_amount = (p.products.discounted_price)
                total_amount += t_amount
    return render(request, 'Shop/cart.html', {'cart': cart, 'total_amount': total_amount})
```

This is what it says in the browser: **local variable 'total_amount' referenced before assignment**.

**Thank you**

Comment: That means you should declare the variable (i.e. total_amount=0) before doing the cumulative sum in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your Variable amount = 0.00 should be renamed to total_amount.

Comment: If I do that the total amount becomes zero as well

Comment: the if statement 'if cart_products:' could be resolving to false, then your total_amount would still return 0.0. There may be an error in 'cart_products = [p for p in Cart.objects.all() if p.buyer == buyer]' or if the if statement is being hit correctly  't_amount = (p.products.discounted_price)' t_amount may be returning a zero.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't have any `cart_products`, python is trying to read the variable total_amount, but it is out of scope. Define it on top of the function.

```
def addtocart(request):
    total_amount = 0.00
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        ....
```